# Launch Profile Initializer: Unable to parse the launchSettings.json file

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio shows the following error box:

> Launch Profile Initializer
>
> Unable to parse the launchSettings.json file.

Where to find which project is causing this issue?
There is no detailed information in the Output window.

Answer (score 4):

Your launchSettings.json has to contain at least `applicationUrl` e.g.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55555",
      "sslPort": 44395
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1020438/launch-profile-initializer.html

Comment: I have added `applicationUrl` to my profile. (I am not using IIS.) It helped in my case (thanks +1), however I would like to know location of a log, where more error details can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue until I put this iisExpress settings back. I used to only have the iis values since that's the only profile I use, but it started complaining until I put those back. Might be true for the opposite too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `iisSettings` Again

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5560",
      "sslPort": 44395
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is still there it seems. In my testing, I managed to get by with only adding `applicationUrl` in whichever profile I had. So the `iisSettings/iisExpress` elements don't seem to be mandatory. This Kestrel profile works for me:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Kestrel": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://yoururl",
      "applicationUrl": "http://dummy" // Required for VS not to show error
    }
  }
}
```